Is it possible to spread the load of a big database operation onto mutliple connections?
A few days ago, I was working on a Quarkus application that manages Panache (active record pattern) entities. I wanted to insert large amounts of data. I'm using the quarkus-jdbc-postgresql and quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache extensions with PostgreSQL as the database.
I noticed that inserting the data takes a very long time (1 million records take about 30 minutes). Manual tests with pure SQL showed that using the ORM results in significant performance degradation. Tracing the actual SQL queries revealed that the SQL commands are being sent serially instead of being batched effectively (I also tried the batch-size configuration parameter but with no success).
I noticed that my Quarkus application only opens a single database connection. I than set the following parameters:
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size: 12
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size: 4

With this configuration, I start with 4 connections, but for my transaction, only a single database connection is used. I tried parralleling the work into multiple virtual threads but this did not change anything.

My Question is now: How can I enforce the usage of multiple database connections for my database transactions?

While we can (theoretically) use multiple connections for one (logical) transaction, I am quite sure that this would mean X/Open-XA transactions, aka. XA-transactions aka. global transactions. This would mean other challenges. --- Can you share the relevant code and the query generated? I suspect that this might be at the heart of the issue.

The exact operation is unfortunately quite complex and finding a simple code example is not easy :/. But basically you could say I have a list of a million entities that are not yet persisted and then call .persist(chunk) for one chunk of this list (10,000). This operation alone takes about 12s which I could measure with pure SQL to a little under a second.

So you call persist(Entity, Entity...) ?

Why should that be faster than persist(Stream<Entity> entities)? The chunk in my previous comment is a stream of 10.000 entities

I didn't say it is faster :) I just tried to figure out what exact method you are using. So it is persist(Stream<Entity> entities)

Hard to say what the problem is without the code and mapping, but here are a few things you can try.

Check the problem is actually on the persisting side, and not with the data loading. If you have no idea, change your code to do everything it currently does (including creating entity objects and populating them), but skip the call to persist -- is it any faster?
To insert multiple entities in a single SQL statement, do not set the batch-size parameter, but the statement-batch-size parameter
Check how you access the Hibernate ORM session from multiple threads. Depending how you do that, virtual threads may be using the same session, which is unlikely to help and more importantly, may lead to failures or data loss, since sessions are not thread safe. If you use @Inject Session session, you're fine; otherwise, maybe not.
Check that the problem is not related to virtual threads. Virtual threads are not absolutely required here, since you'll likely use only a few threads, about as many as the max-size setting on your connection pool. With so few threads, traditional thread pools may work just as well (or better, if there is indeed a problem with virtual threads).
Consider flushing/clearing your Hibernate ORM session periodically, e.g. session.flush();session.clear(); every 100 items. This can help lower the memory pressure on your app by sending all these 100 items to the database (but not committing) and freeing memory in your JVM.
If possible, consider smaller transactions, e.g. 200 items at a time. Only keep that change if it actually improves performance -- maybe it will, maybe it won't. Remember you can use QuarkusTransaction to easily control transaction boundaries.

